# What is the relationship between the Cosmological Constant and the Cosmological Principle?

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-constant

I believe I've misunderstood a relationship between the [cosmological constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant) and the [cosmological principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle) having read:

> Einstein introduces his cosmological constant which attributes, in the form of an assumption, a structural uniformity – of the distribution of matter and radiation

Which I took to mean that the cosmological constant was the mathematical expression of the cosmological principle. I can't find any explicit statement of this anywhere, so I now assume I'm wrong. What is the relationship then (if any) between the constant and the principle? And secondly, if the cosmological constant isn't the means by which the cosmological principle exerts influence over the Big Bang Model (BBM), how significant is the principle for the BBM? In what ways?

Comment: There’s no relationship. We would model the universe as homogenous and isotropic even if there were no cosmological constant.

Comment: Try this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.1300

Comment: Cheers Smith for the clear answer & thanks Reign, I'll check that out.